# Android option menu hidden by software buttons

Tags: android, menu, xamarin.android

I have a problem with the option menu on a tablet equiped with the software buttons. On my smartphone (with physical buttons) everything looks correct: [smartphone screenshot](http://postimage.org/image/nlmis4qg3/)

but on the tablet option menu is partially hidden by the software buttons bar:
[tablet screenshot](http://postimage.org/image/uh6rb8kwz/)

I looked at other aplications and they just display menu above the s/w buttons... I don't know what I did wrong? Google search don't gave me any useful hints, maybe someone here will know how to avoid this behavior? Aplication is written in Monodroid but I don't really think that it has any importance. On Android emulators this problem exists as well.

Comment: If you are hardcoding the size of the layout with specific pixels it will probably do this!

Comment: Please show us the layout.

Comment: Cheesebaron - your post suggested me an idea... I've tested this layout in a separate project but, unfortunatelly, it works fine. So the problem must be - like njzk2 and Davos555 wrote - with some adjustments that are made to the layout from my code...